# How to target only specific <span> tags inside a div using css?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to target only the 1st level  tags inside a div. Here is my code:

```
<div class="main">
 <span id="j_id0:j_id42">
    <span>Customer Info</span>
 </span>
 <span id="j_id0:j_id4">
    <span>Billing Address</span>
    <div>Text</div>
 </span>
 <span id="j_id0:j_id61">
    <span id="j_id4:22df">Shipping Address</span>
    <div>Text</div>
 </span>
```

Want to target all the span tags with dynamic ids and not the inner span tags. That is I want to add some specific css properties to all the 1st occurrence of each span tags(the one with ids) within the main div.  Is this possible using css? If not how to do this using javascript?

Note that there may be other ids inside the inner span tags. Want to target only `<span id="j_id0:j_id42">` , `<span id="j_id0:j_id4">`, `<span id="j_id0:j_id61">`. That is only the 1st occurrence of the spans inside main div.

Comment: .main > span { ... } its just a simple css selector

Comment: .main > span will select all of the child span tags within .main. To target the second tier spans if wanted further down the line, use .main > span > span.

Answer (score 5):

The simplest one is to use `>`:

```
.main > span{}
```

*Want to target all the span tags with dynamic ids*

if we consider it then you can change it to:

```
.main span[id]{}
```

*I want to add some specific css properties to all the 1st occurrence of each span tags(the one with ids) within the main div*

Then you can use it:

```
.main span[id]:first-child{}
```

### For your last edit:

*Want to target only `<span id="j_id0:j_id42">` , `<span id="j_id0:j_id4">`, `<span id="j_id0:j_id61">`.*

```
.main span[id] span{}
```

```css
.main span[id] span{color:red; font-weight:bold;}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <span id="j_id0:j_id42">
    <span>Customer Info</span>
  </span>
  <span id="j_id0:j_id4">
    <span>Billing Address</span>
  <div>Text</div>
  </span>
  <span id="j_id0:j_id61">
    <span id-"id21">Shipping Address</span>
  <div>Text</div>
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use selector with attributes contain some word: [Link](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attribute_value_contains.asp)

```
.main span[id~="j_id"] { ... }
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution but there are also inner span tags with id starting with "j_id". So we cannot use this.

Comment: Well the `~=` search elements that contain the word. In my example i use 'j_jd' but you can use some other word like '0:j_id'  `.main span[id~="0:j_id"] { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

you can try `.main span[id^="j_id"] { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

For all span tags with dynamic ids:

```
.main > span or span[id^="j_id0:j_"]
```

For specific span tags with dynamic ids. k from 1..n

```
.main > span:nth-child(k)
```